# IOS monitor photo album change when app is in background

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, observers, ios-camera

I'm building an app that is supposed to monitor picture taking even if the app is in the background.

For example:
A user opens the app, insert some settings and then puts the app in the background (locks the device or something). When the user opens the device again and take a photo with the camera, my app needs to catch that event.

I read some tutorials about the `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification` class and didn't exactly understand if this is what am I looking for because it doesn't say if this runs when app is in background.

I was wondering if someone here has some experience with this kind of thing and can give me some input about this kind of thing maybe an observer? Maybe a service? Any ideas?

Comment: The notification isn't sent to you when your app isn't running. You need to iterate the assets in the library and check for new items.